# Issue where Last_sent_time and Last_received_time columns in DMV dm_hadr_database_replica_states does not get updated

Tags: sql-server, alwayson, dmv, availability-group

I have an issue on 2016 where Last_sent_time and Last_received_time columns in the DMV dm_hadr_database_replica_states does not get updated.  Coincidently we are seeing issues related to timeouts when the times are finally updated which makes me think there is some kind of pressure happening or the redo logs are not being sent to the secondary correctly.

This seems to be related to CDC as one database on my instance has CDC enabled and does not update, the other one doesn't have CDC enabled and does update.

Looking through different KBs etc In the following CUs for 2017 and 2019, this issue is fixed

KB5005226 - Cumulative Update 26 for SQL Server 2017
KB5007182 - Cumulative Update 14 for SQL Server 2019

However checking through 2016 SP3 and Hotfix it's not, probably because it is no longer under Extended Support.  I understand there has to be a cut off but I would still like to understand what the issue is these 2 fixes were sorting.

Is there any way I can find more information of what the root cause was for these fixes?  I can't find anything online and the KBs above don't have links to any known KBs

Comment: For further details I think you'll need to open a support case with Microsoft. They've become rather tight-lipped lately about what's in a fix (in most cases the title is the extent of the information they expose publicly - in some cases this makes it impossible to figure out _what the issue even was_, never mind how they fixed it). On the plus side it's possible they have a private hotfix branch just waiting for you, because it's been 6 months since the last public fix and you can't possibly be the first 2016 customer who has hit this issue.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I opened a case last night so waiting to hear back from their engineers.

Comment: When you start interacting with them just say, look, I think I'm suffering from the same issue as <these two KB numbers>, is there a private hotfix available for 2016? Though they will probably only be willing to do that if you have SA and/or an extended support contract. Their first instinct is going to be to tell you to upgrade.

Comment: Sounds a good plan, thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

Opened a ticket with Microsoft who were unable to supply a hotfix for me or offer any information about what is contained within the fixes for 2017 and 2019.  So unfortunately there is no resolution for this if you are on 2016, other than upgrade versions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also exist even when on SQL Server 2017 CU31

Comment: @Pokiri

Did Cumulative Update 26 for SQL Server 2017 (KB5007182) not fix the issue?  I don't have any 2017 instances set up for Always On so nothing to test it against.

Comment: DSDmark, not sure if this message was for me or Pokiri, if it was for me then there is no solution to explain for SQL Server 2016.  Microsoft would not tell me what was causing this to happen, or suggest a way to fix it.  The only option available is to upgrade versions to 2017 and 2019.